# Simple char[] assignement in C#

Tags: c#, string, list, char, type-conversion

I'm trying to assign a `char[,]` matrix to be equal to a `List<string>`.
I've done this with this code:

```cs
List <string> stringList = new List<string>();
// stringList assignments not displayed
//...

char[,] dataMatrix = new char[stringList.Count, 256];
for (int i=0;i< stringList.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j< stringList[i].Length; j++)
    {
        char[] charFromString = stringList[i].Substring(j, 1).ToCharArray();
        dataMatrix[i, j] = charFromString[0];
    }
}
```

This is seems like poor coding, how should this be done?

Comment: Instead of Substring plus the rest, use `stringList[i][j]` to get the char at that position

Comment: Try following : char[][] dataMatrix = stringList.Select(x => x.ToCharArray()).ToArray();

Comment: What if `stringList` contains strings of **different lengths**? e.g. `stringList = new List<string>() {"a", "abcde", "xyz"};`. How should `char[,] dataMatrix` look like?

Comment: @jdweng unfortunately the array needs to be a multidimensional array, a jagged array will not work in this case.  Pity as this is a very nice solution.

Comment: Now it is not jaggered :             List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
            int maxWidth = stringList.Max(x => x.Length);
            char[][] dataMatrix = stringList.Select(x => x.ToCharArray().Concat(new string('\0', maxWidth - x.Length)).ToArray()).ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

Using @Hans Keﬆing suggestion above the code can be writen as:

```html
List <string> stringList = new List<string>();
// stringList assignments not displayed
//...

char[,] dataMatrix = new char[stringList.Count, 256];
for (int i=0;i< stringList.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j< stringList[i].Length; j++)
    {
        dataMatrix[i, j] = stringList[i][j];
    }
}
```

I could not get @jdweng's solution to work for my case as a multidimensional array was required in my case and a jagged array was not suitable (i.e. dataMatrix[,] was required and not dataMatrix[][]).